# Can not filter user explorer google analytics

Tags: google-analytics

I am using userID feature.
And i have two user type with example userId:
12345678-User
12345678-Visitor
Goto Audience -> user explorer. And i want to using regex to collect by user type but match regex not working.

Answer (score 1):

This doesn't seem to be doable unfortunately on User Explorer report. Possible workaround would be, create a Google Sheet with Google Analytics add-on to upload the data. Create another sheet with high-level report broken down by specified userIds that extract data from GA.